# How to run Jcalltracer

Tags: java, jvmti

Hey guys I'm having trouble opening jcalltracer, an open source program on sourceforge that reverse engineers a Java program into sequence diagram. I got error when I was trying to add the following to JVM -

java -agentpath:C:\calltracer\jvmti\calltracer5.dll=traceFile-C:\calltracer\call.trace,filterFile-C:\calltracer\filters.txt,outputType-xml,usage-uncontrolled -Djava.library.path=C:\calltracer\jvmti -Dcalltracerlib=calltracer5

Error -

Error occured during initialisation of VM
Could not find agent library C:\calltracer\jvmti\calltracer5.dll in absolute path, with error: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

I am using Windows 7 x64 and I'm very sure that I installed the x64 version after checking the java sdk I downloaded and doing a java -version check. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the calltracer5.dll has been compiled to work on a 32bit platform. You will need to recompile for 64bit.